# How can I add multiple external IPs to my dedicated server?

Tags: networking, debian

I cannot seem to find an answer for my setup. I have 5 useable IP addresses that are not hooked up to my server. The interface is lo / enol not eth0. Below I have tried using some eth0 guides on adding the IPs, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eno1
iface eno1 inet static
address 192.0.2.102
netmask 255.255.255.248
gateway 192.0.2.101
dns-nameservers 192.0.2.3 192.0.2.3

auto enol:0
iface eno1 inet static
address 192.0.2.103
netmask 255.255.255.248
gateway 192.0.2.101

auto enol:1
iface eno1 inet static
address 192.0.2.104
netmask 255.255.255.248
gateway 192.0.2.101

auto enol:2
iface eno1 inet static
address 192.0.2.105
netmask 255.255.255.248
gateway 192.0.2.101

auto enol:3
iface eno1 inet static
address 192.0.2.106
netmask 255.255.255.248
gateway 192.0.2.101
```

This is a debian dedicated server, thanks.

Comment: the auto and iface names need to be the same, also you can only have on default gateway

Comment: You have mistyped `eno1` as `enol` in numerous places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use the appropriate interface names for each virtual interface.

replace:

```
auto enol:0
iface eno1 inet static
```

with:

```
auto enol:0
iface eno1:0 inet static
```

Make sure to only use one gateway, then you should be able to get it to work automagically.

Personally I would also remove:

```
allow-hotplug eno1
```

and replace it with:

```
auto eno1
```

I found that the former gives problems, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that enol (with the letter "L") probably doesn't exist.

You probably mean eno1 (number "One"). If so, I suggest you to correct your configuration like so:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
iface eno1 inet static
address 192.0.2.102
netmask 255.255.255.248
gateway 192.0.2.101
dns-nameservers 192.0.2.3 192.0.2.3 # < is this really necessary? (debian has resolv.conf which you can use for dns)

auto eno1:0
iface eno1 inet static
address 192.0.2.103
netmask 255.255.255.248
gateway 192.0.2.101

auto eno1:1
iface eno1 inet static
address 192.0.2.104
netmask 255.255.255.248
gateway 192.0.2.101

auto eno1:2
iface eno1 inet static
address 192.0.2.105
netmask 255.255.255.248
gateway 192.0.2.101

auto eno1:3
iface eno1 inet static
address 192.0.2.106
netmask 255.255.255.248
gateway 192.0.2.101
```

Also, the output of the command:

```
ip link show
```

can list all your interface(s) and their name(s) so you can be sure of the naming.